# DateTimePicker: modify hours when increasing/decreasing minutes

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have written an application in Visual Studio VB to plot some data as a function of the date. Near the graph I have a DateTimePIcker that moves a marker line on the graph.

Basically it works, but when I click the button "Move Up" or Move down" on the DateTimePicker and the value of minutes go over 59, the object does not update automativally the value of hours. It starts again 1 hour earlier.

I tried to search something, or some options to fix this bug, but I do not have found anything.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a similar code that works even if you click move down:

```
Private intHours As Integer = 0
Private intMinutes As Integer = 0

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

    Dim intOldHours As Integer = Me.intHours
    Dim intOldMinutes As Integer = Me.intMinutes

    Me.intHours = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Hour
    Me.intMinutes = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Minute

    If intOldHours = Me.intHours Then
        If intOldMinutes = 59 AndAlso Me.intMinutes = 0 Then
            Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.AddHours(1)
        ElseIf intOldMinutes = 0 AndAlso Me.intMinutes = 59 Then
            Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.AddHours(-1)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't this get to 59 then keep adding an hour every time? since the minutes never gets reset to 0

Comment: no need to reset minutes since move up/down already change this value; code modified to also work with move down